# List - Comma Delimited - Where return specific element

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  I have a list (no key:pair) that is comma delimited.

Layman's terms, I want to return the 4th element when I find an item in the list.   Example if I find the item Pear I want to return the value 0.3.

Example List:

```
"Apple,P03100B0B0,,1,0.8,0,0.9,0"

"Pear,KO3100B0B0,,1,0.3,0,0.2,0"
```

I've looked at leveraging linkq but haven't got it to work.

Wish something like this would work.

```
var res = listString.Select(x => x.Split(',')[4]).Select(a => a.Contains("Pear"));
```

Comment: Will the format always be the same -- will the key you're searching always be the first element? Or could the string be `Some,Value,Pear` and still match?

Comment: @dvo - Format will always be the same and my first element will be unique.

Comment: great. see my answer and the text below the code about `.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in LINQ. You can use `Select` to split the list, then if the split list contains your key (in this case "Pear"), then select index `4` of the split list. With your sample data, this returns a list of 1 string: `{ "0.3" }`. If there are no results, the list will be returned with a `Count` of 0.

```
var res = listString
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Where(x => x.Contains("Pear"))
    .Select(x => x[4])
    .ToList();
```

If you only want the first result or only expect one result because you have a controlled data set, replace `.ToList();` with `.FirstOrDefault();` to return only the string value (`"0.3"`). If there are no matches with your search key, the string value will be `null`.

Comment: In case there can be only one item with a certain key, replace `ToList` by `FirstOrDefault`. The result will be a string instead of a list of strings. Instead of checking all columns with `x.Contains("Pear")` you could just check the first element with `x[0] == "Pear"`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Good point. He did comment saying the format would always be the same so he could do `x[0] == "Pear"` and have faster results! Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Just split your string into an array and get the 4 element, if the format of your string will always be the same.

Something like this:

```
string[] result = yourString.Split(',');
if(result[0].ToString() == "Pear")
{
  string finalresult = result[3].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability I might do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in listString)
{
    var segments = item.Split(',');
    if(segments[0] == "Pear") // change how you do this comparison according to your needs
        // do something with segments[4]       
}
```

...possibly adding in a little bit of handling in case the string is malformed. For example, to ignore rows that can't be processed you could add this right after splitting the string:

```
if(segments.Length < 5) continue;
```

That will handle both empty lines and lines than don't have enough values for the next step to make sense. `continue` just skips to the next item in the `foreach` loop.

You could possibly find a way to do all of this on one line, but it would take longer to write, longer to read, and the same amount of time to execute. Imagine yourself coming upon some code you have to understand or maintain - would you prefer to see the code above, or long, one-line LINQ query?

Answer (score -1):

So you are correct you need to `.Split` your listString first. As it may contain empty elements, remove them. Then check if your split list has specific element like "Pear" and select 4th element (if list has 4th element)

```
var str = "Pear,KO3100B0B0,,1,0.3,0,0.2,0";
var res = str.Split(',').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

if(res.Contains("Pear") && res.Length > 2){
    Console.WriteLine(res[3].ToString());
}
```

*Note: Arrays are 0 based when indexing them.*